# how to find the text from the multiple same attribute in watir?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I want to find and click the `Line Lo` value from the following value. The following `li` had more than 100 records has same class name. How to find the `Line Lo` and click that value.

```
<div id="loc">
  <ul id="tab">
    <li class="criteria">
      <div class="bud">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="attr">Code Lo</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="criteria">
      <div class="bud">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="attr">Line Lo</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="criteria">
      <div class="bud">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="attr">Add Lo</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When I tried, `browser.ul(id: "tab").li(class: "criteria").div(text: "Line Lo")`

Got the failure error.

```
Unable to locate element, using(:class => "Criteria", :tag_name=>"li"
```

I tried different, different attributes to find the Text `Line Lo` and I failed.

Also, This element is like 45th, so is it possible to scroll down and flash this value before click?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you have a lot of nested containers there..  do you know which one you are wanting to click on?  is it an LI (list item) or a Div inside the LI?    Does that text appear anywhere else on the page or in the list?

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply. I need to click inside the div and the text is unique in this div.

Comment: "I need to click inside the div" makes no sense.  WHICH div is "the div"?  There are THREE of them nested one inside the other inside each list item, each with a different class.  Which of those three divs is 'the div'?

Comment: Again Sorry, I need to click the `<div class="attr">`. Now its working. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks, I can clarify my answer now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original thing you tried

```
browser.ul(id: "tab").li(class: "criteria").div(text: "Line Lo")
```

failed because when there is more than one element that could match the criteria you specify, watir will use the first one it finds.   So what that is asking watir to do would equate to the following in english

*Find the first un-ordered list with the id 'tab', 
then inside that list find the first list item with the class 'criteria', 
then inside that list item, find a div with the text 'Line Lo'.*

Since the first LI inside that list does not contain a div with that text, it fails.

**To click the innermost div** (*based on comments, this is what you are trying to do*)

```
browser.div(:class => "attr", :text => "Line Lo").click
```

aka *Find me a div with the class "attr" AND the text "Line Lo", and then have the div click itself*

---

*these other options were presented when it was not clear exactly which div the OP was after, but I'm leaving them as they might be informative to other folks struggling with similar issues*

To click the div that contains the one above (the parent).

```
browser.div(:class => "inner", :text => "Line Lo").click
```

if that parent div had no uniqueness (no class etc) you could still get to it like this

```
browser.div(:class => "attr", :text => "Line Lo").parent.click
```

To click the li tag that holds all that stuff

```
browser.li(:class => "criteria", :text => "Line Lo").click
```

For any of those, if you need to restrict to just looking inside that particular list, then specify like this

```
browser.ul(:id => "tab").li(:class => "criteria", :text => "Line Lo").click
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
browser.ul(:id => 'tab').div(:class => 'attr', :text => 'Line Lo').click
```

When `.click` is used, it should get scrolled into view before being clicked.

Comment: hi if i have two class name in which the text container? how to pick up? like `<div class="attr page">Line Lo</div>`

Comment: You can include both class names in the locator: `browser.ul(:id => 'tab').div(:class => 'attr page', :text => 'Line Lo').click`